# Proper way to handle race condition for 3 microservices. (Promise.all ?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, microservices, race-condition

How sure I am that promise.all will run the promise request one by one?

Scenario I have 3 services. `frontend`, `uploader`, and `api`
`frontend` is the client, `uploader` handles google storage related actions, and `api` handles normal REST stuff.

On my database I have something like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  directory: 'googlestorage/dir/randomstring.jpg',
  user_id: 100
}
```

Now in my frontend, I have a function that triggers an update to the directory and deletes the old one so the end result should be.

```
{
  id: 1,
  directory: 'googlestorage/new_directory/anotherRandomString.jpg',
  user_id: 100
}
```

In my `frontend` I need to make sure that the call to the `api` to update the record on the database should go first before deleting it by calling the `fileuploader`.

but on my `fileuploader` I pass the `directory` to check and validate whether the user is allowed to delete the file or not.

But If I update the database first, then I won't be able to check if the record is still on user's because the data is already updated and will not match the old one.

I also don't want to delete the file first because what if the request to update the database fails?

I tried doing:

```
await Promise.all([requestUpdateToApi, requestToDeleteFileUploader]);
```

But it's the same, one will be updated first or will be deleted first before the other.

I wanna do it so if one request fails, the other should not proceed too - is there a good solution for this without touching the database structure?

Comment: `doFirstRequest().then(result => doSecondRequest())`?

Comment: did that too, but If I do the `firstRequest` first then it will update the record on the database and I won't be able to query that record anymore on my second request

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can just edit the directory so each files are stored in `randomDirectoryName/{userId}/{filename}`.

So if I delete the file, I just use the `id` and the `user_id` to validate the data then delete the path under the `/{userId}/{directoryFromRequest}` without worrying about race condition.